# SQL Job Step created via wizard does not correctly set server & database_name values

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, ssms

I've recently been tasked with migrating a database from SQL Server 2005 to 2008R2. This has all been accomplished without any issues, but one part of the system requires a Snapshot Replication to be run as part of an overnight SQL Job.

So there's a step within the job setup with the command

```
-Publisher [ServerName] -PublisherDB [DatabaseName] -Distributor [ServerName] -Publication [ReplicationName] -DistributorSecurityMode 1
```

But when this step is run, it fails with the error

```
The step is improperly defined and so could not be run.  The step failed.
```

Now when I compare this step with the Job created automatically when replication was setup, they are identical.
But the automatically created job runs just fine.

I scripted the two jobs out to a query window (Script Job as > Create To > New Query Window) and I can see that the job created via the UI Wizard specifies the @database_name parameter to be 'master', and the @server parameter is not set at all.

However the automatically created job sets the @database_name to be 'distribution', and the @server parameter is set.

My question is, how can I set up this job via the provided SSMS UI so that the job will run correctly?
I would prefer to provide the client with instructions that walk them through the wizard (with screenshots) rather than providing them with a script that they have to manually edit.